# Best practices using Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data, swift2

Should I have different managed object contexts for reading and writing? Should I implement the MOC for reading as parent-child? What could be the best implementation of the MOC for writing?

Comment: Parent child implementation can cause slow performance and over complication. The answer to your question is very dependant on your situation.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? I would like to be enlightened regarding with this.

Comment: Based on your question and other comments in this thread, I suggest you use a single main-queue context as it is the simplest approach.  When you have read the documentation and understand some of the intricacies of multithreaded in regards to CoreData, then come back and ask more specific questions.  Until then, it's like trying to explain the central limit theorem to someone who has no knowledge of mean, variance, independent variables, or normal distributions.

Comment: Can you suggest some links, blogs, and articles aside from Apple's documentation?

Comment: Apple's documentation is actually quite good for most of Core Data, and I'd suggest starting there.  If you open up the documentation in Xcode, you can see the Core Data section.  That section includes all the reference documentation, and sections for all the WWDC videos about Core Data, all the specialized programming guides, and the source code for a number of full example applications.  I would also recommend Tom Harrington's Core Data book.

Comment: @Jody Hagins is right. The docs are good and a single MOC is the simplest way of using core data. I tend to temporarily create a private queue MOC when I feel that I should perform a fetch on a background thread.

Comment: I'd also recommend [this blog](https://www.objc.io/issues/4-core-data/core-data-overview/).

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to setup a stack, and each has its pros and cons.

The simplest thing to do, until you are more comfortable with Core Data, is as follows:

Create a parent MOC with a concurrency type of private queue.  This will be your writer, as it will do so in the background.

Create a child MOC with a concurrency type of main queue.  This will be your reader on the main thread.

If you need to make changes from the main thread, you have to make sure to save both contexts to make them persistent.  It's better if you can dispatch all writes directly to the parent for background processing.  Use FRCs and notification handlers to know when to refresh the child.

P.S.  I never use this approach in my apps, but I have a well-developed core data stack that I carry with me from project to project.

Comment: What could be the most complex thing to do but still the best practice? Can you share your well-developed core data stack? At least discuss an overview how to come up with that kind of stack.

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out there are a number of factors that determine how and why you do this.  The most significant of those, in my mind, is whether or not you need to support multi-threading.  Here's a good link that explains (with visuals) the parent / child paradigm.  http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/core-data-from-scratch-concurrency--cms-22131

I use SSDataKit to help with the Core Data setup and then extend where I need to.  In my apps that are highly parallel I create a new MOC for every NSOperation with the relationships: Private Queue -> Main Queue -> Temporary Child Queue (these operations are run on background threads).  In simpler apps I use basic SSDataKit (parent/child) setup and that's that.